# Text to Speech from EditText number by number

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to speech from edittext by number by number.
Let there is 2 and 0 in edittext,
TTS speaks to twenty.
I don't want to like that.
I want to speech one number by number like that two, zero...
please help me...
Sorry for my english....

Comment: Why cant you just put a space between the numbers so that it doesn't actually read as twenty in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can get every Character with:

```
    String editTextString=yourEditText.getText().toString();
      char numbers[]=editTextString.toCharArray();
       for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
       Log.d("Test","Number:"+numbers[i]);
          //here you can speakOut()
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement edittext.onTextChangedListener..

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {



        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {


        }
    });
```

and just put your code in afterTextChanged..

and see this [code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) for texToSpeech